# Is that true that blockchain can still be centralized?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain-interoperation

1. Contracts can deploy contracts; and
2. There are hidden variables in contracts; and
3. Contract can restrict only the deployer can execute some functions.

Thus, I can create a central contract like a centralized serverless server,
and control all spawned instances of client contracts with it.

Then "decentralized" blockchain is just another form of a centralized network. Is that true?

Answer (score 2):

In the Ethereum blockchain there isn't "hidden variables", all the data is available for anyone to read. A contract could make harder for users to read some data but they cannot hide it.

A contract can implement access control so only a subset of user can interact with it. For example multisig wallet requires such feature so only the owners can withdraw from it.

Ethereum is a decentralized blockchain because anyone can read it, and if you pay the transaction fee you can write to it. A contract with access control doesn't change the nature of the blockchain.

Comment: Using blockchain wallet as example, if the contract implements a withdrawal restriction of withdrawal that only the minter can change on/off, even everyone can read and pay gas for interaction, the balance is still being unchangeable, am I right?

Comment: @Urology2103 Yes. Anyone can execute a contract function, but the contract could implement an access control to allow only certain addresses to make changes to it. You don't need to pay for read the contract data, it is publicly available, you only pay for executing a transaction.